# Firebase + react : read document in auth state changed and add it to context

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

Based on https://dev.to/bmcmahen/using-firebase-with-react-hooks-21ap I have a authentication hook to get user state and firestore hook to get user data.

```
export const useAuth = () => {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState(() => { const user = firebase.auth().currentUser return { initializing: !user, user, } })
  function onChange(user) {
    setState({ initializing: false, user })
  }

  React.useEffect(() => {
    // listen for auth state changes
    const unsubscribe = firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(onChange)
    // unsubscribe to the listener when unmounting
    return () => unsubscribe()
  }, [])

  return state
}
```

```
function useIngredients(id) {
  const [error, setError] = React.useState(false)
  const [loading, setLoading] = React.useState(true)
  const [ingredients, setIngredients] = React.useState([])

  useEffect(
    () => {
      const unsubscribe = firebase
        .firestore()
        .collection('recipes')
        .doc(id)
        .collection('ingredients') .onSnapshot( snapshot => { const ingredients = [] snapshot.forEach(doc => { ingredients.push(doc) }) setLoading(false) setIngredients(ingredients) }, err => { setError(err) } )

      return () => unsubscribe()
    },
    [id]
  )

  return {
    error,
    loading,
    ingredients,
  }
}
```

Now in my app I can use this to get user state and data

```
function App() {
  const { initializing, user } = useAuth()
  const [error,loading,ingredients,] = useIngredients(user.uid);
  if (initializing) {
    return <div>Loading</div>
  }

  return (
    <userContext.Provider value={{ user }}> <UserProfile /> </userContext.Provider> )
}
```

Since UID is null before auth state change trigger, firebase hook is getting called with empty key.

How to fetch data in this scenario once we understand that user is logged in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May be you can add your document read inside auth hook.

```
export const useAuth = () => {
    const [userContext, setUserContext] = useState<UserContext>(() => {
        const context: UserContext = {
            isAuthenticated: false,
            isInitialized: false,
            user: auth.currentUser,
            userDetails: undefined
        };
        return context;
    })

    function onChange (user: firebase.User | null) {
        if (user) {
            db.collection('CollectionName').doc(user.uid)
                .get()
                .then(function (doc) {
                    //set it to context
                    })
                });

        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        const unsubscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged(onChange)
        return () => unsubscribe()
    }, [])

    return userContextState
}
```

You can use some loading spinner in your provider to wait for things to complete.